# How to record call in android? Is it possible?

Tags: android, audio-recording, telephony, phone-call

I want to record call from android phone.
I am using android.media.MediaRecorder pckg.

Also used following code:

```
mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

But I didn't succeed in recording an incoming call.
Can anyone recommend a tested code snippet?

Also,
Is this true?
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c2bc85eb60ae2aa5?pli=1
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard distributions of Android does not support it till now.

You can vote up these if you want:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4075

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117

Comment: is it? what is the use of setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)

Comment: until now, no use :)  read the discussions in the two links i provided. if u had read them, u'd not make this comment

Comment: You seem to imply that there is a non-standard distribution of Android which does support this. Which one would that be?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a software problem and I don't think the baseband firmware vendors will fix this. Most likely because it's illegal in most western countries to record calls without consent of the other person.

Comment: Most states in the US are one party notification, same with some EU countries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_recording_laws

Comment: not sure becoz of this, I think MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL API is not working. thoughts?