# can we record while making a call in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to record the conversation while making a call in android? Is there any specifications required for this? Can someone plz give me an idea about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to record call in android? Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862857/how-to-record-call-in-android-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1):

Android OS doesn't provide any direct high level API for that!

Also have a look at: 
[How to record call in android? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862857/how-to-record-call-in-android-is-it-possible)