# How to make sure my Android device supports call recording?

Tags: android, android-manifest, recording, phone-call

Is there a way to specify in the manifest that the application must have access to `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL`? (or any other form of call recording which I'm not familiar with yet and would be really glad to be :) )

Comment: Have you looked here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862857/how-to-record-call-in-android-is-it-possible?

Comment: I've seen many posts saying that call recording isn't possible on Android using this (or any) API. Fortunately, this does work on my Samsung Galaxy S2 :)
What I want is to be able to forbid installation on devices that don't support this.