# Streaming call voice in android?

Tags: android, call

I just came to know that it's possible to record call voice (both incoming and outgoing) in android, I want to know about any API or methods which can tether this call voice during a call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it is not supported to record a call but just read the below answer.

on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862913/402637)

Comment: SURE??? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.record.my.call&hl=en  just does that...

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for same thing, i found arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544992/call-audio-stream-modification-in-android-4-0-ics) pretty intresting and convincing ! hope this helps you